# Find out how many iterations done by linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to know how many iteratons were done by LINQ. so i wrote a simple query

```
string xx = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

char search = 'f';

int j = 0;

var result = xx.Select((b, i) => 
{
    j++;
    return b.Equals(search) ? i : -1;
})
.Where(i => 
{
    j++;
    return i != -1;
});

MessageBox.Show(j.ToString());
```

I thought that `j` would contain the number of iterations done but surprisingly it remains 0. Why is it so? and secondly how to find out how many iteratons were done by LINQ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because LINQ is [lazy evaluated](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2006/10/04/lazy-evaluation-_2800_and-in-contrast_2c00_-eager-evaluation_2900_.aspx). So the lambdas are invoked only when it's necessary.

Perform `.ToList()` in the end to trigger it, for example.

Comment: Oh, how can i forgot that. Thanks.

Comment: @Nikhil Agrawal: Btw, wouldn't `j` finally have the value of `xx.Count() * 2` ?

Comment: Yeah that's what i wanted to found out.

Comment: Does lazy evaluation happens with query syntax of LINQ also?

Comment: @Nikhil Agrawal: From what I remember - it's just the another way of expressing the same logic. So eventually both the notations result into the similar expression tree.

Comment: Oh yes. I remember again that CLR at compile-time converts query syntax to method syntax (Lambda Expression). I read it here.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal the CLR doesn't do anything at compile time. The compiler does.

Answer (score 1):

How do you know it remains zero; did you print it after the `var result =` line? That is because LINQ uses deferred execution. So even though you called `Select()` and `Where()`, they didn't actually *do* anything yet.  You can force it to execute by calling `ToList()` or `ToArray()` at the end of the LINQ chain.

Comment: The same logic follows. The deferred execution of the lamdas has not happened yet.